# delete dict in list from dict in list

Tags: python

I have two lists (with dicts in it):

```
old_device_data_list = [{'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e34545fac49fbff5'), 'device_id': 5, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 100, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 100, 'sum': 100}}]

result = [{'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e3997640fac49fbff5'), 'device_id': 5, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 100, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 100, 'sum': 100}}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e3997640fac49fbff6'), 'device_id': 4, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 180, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 180, 'sum': 180}}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e3997640fac49fbff8'), 'device_id': 3, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 50, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 50, 'sum': 50}}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e3997640fac49fbff7'), 'device_id': 4, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 120, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 120, 'sum': 120}}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f48c8e3997640fac49fbff9'), 'device_id': 3, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 28, 9, 5, 39, 827000), 'values': {'count': 210, 'late': 0, 'max': 0, 'min': 0, 'on_time': 210, 'sum': 210}}]
```

I want to delete the dicts from the `old_device_data_list` out of the `result` list. I tried it with numpy with:

```
numpy.setdiff1d(result, old_device_data_list)
```

Then I got error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: is any of your dict values unique to each dict? for example, is `'_id'` a unique value for each dict or would there be a duplicate of same id?

Comment: One way would be create a ``set`` of object_id from ``old_device_data_list`` & use that to apply filter on ``result``

Comment: @Ehsan _id is an ObjectId from pymongo, I don't know if I can use it. (Id, datetime) should be unique

Comment: I would suggest create a list/set of tuples of (id, datetime) and filter by that then.

Answer (score 1):

The description of `numpy.setdiff1d` says:

> Return the sorted, unique values in `ar1` that are not in `ar2`.

In order to sort the values, it needs to compare them using the `<` operator. But dictionaries cannot be compared like this. The relation "smaller than" is not defined for dictionaries.

NumPy is designed for working with numeric values, not for arbitrary Python data structures.

You could use a simple list comprehension to create a list of those dictionaries that are in `result` but not in `old_device_data_list`:

```
result = [d for d in result if d not in old_device_data_list]
```